# C++ to Java division operator

Tags: java, c++

C++ code: `if (!(number % i)) {`

Java code: `if (!(number % i == 0)) {`

Is that right?

**Correct version:**

**Java code: `if ((number % i == 0)) {`**

Comment: What's the question? Is *what* right?

Comment: `if (number % i != 0)` works too...

Comment: My advice is to you use the `(number % i == 0)` in both languages. It works, and it makes the intention clear. In normal cases, you will not gain from using `if (!(number % i))`.

Comment: Your first version is right.  Your "Correct version" is missing `!`

Comment: This is the modulus operator, not the division operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct, yes. **They don't do the same thing though**.

In Java you need the comparison because there's no automatic conversion to a boolean value.

The equivalent C++ code would be either

```
if (!(number % i == 0))
```

or simply

```
if (number % i)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, that would be correct.**

Java, treats `boolean` as a `separate data type` which has 2 distinct values: **true** and **false**

C++ regards integer `0` to be equivalent to false and other values to be true.

However, you have inverted the logic in your statements.

```
if (!(number % i)) { //returns true if number is divisible by i
if (!(number % i == 0)) { //returns true if number is not divisible by i
```